# How to modify incoming HTTPS and HTTP requests with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently looking to create a python script that looks at incoming HTTP or HTTPS traffic and changes it. This needs to be 100% automatic. This will run on my local computer. 
I need something like this:

```
def Change(request):
    #Get all incoming HTTPS and HTTP traffic
    #Change the request


while true:
    #Get all incoming HTTPS and HTTP traffic
    Change(request)
```

This obviously would be more complicated than that. I need to change website html when a user is connecting to a page. For example change a incoming html file from this:

```
<form action="/example.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Bob"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mc Bob"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

To

```
<title>Hey</title>
<form action="/example.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Bob"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mc Bob"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Thanks, sorry if I messed up the code a little bit I am still learning.

Comment: There are potentially a lot of different parts of this. Can you be more specific as to what exactly you're stuck on and what you've done to try to solve it so far?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
from functools import wraps

def request_decorator(view_func):
    def _decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something with request before the view_func call
        response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return response
    return wraps(view_func)(_decorator)

# Use it like this
@request_decorator
def foo(request): 
    return HttpResponse('...')
```

Comment: Yes, its not the layout I am struggling on it is intercepting the HTTP/HTTPS request and editing it.

Comment: This decorator's purpose is to 'intercept' the request and 'edit' it as you wish. You gotta put your 'editing' code where the comment "# do something with request ..." is

Comment: I understand that, I am just confused on how you actually intercept the HTTP/HTTPS request and modify it. But thanks anyway.